# Is parallel processing a solution for RAM shortage in R due to a large dataset?

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing, future, sparklyr

I would like to do several machine learning techniques (logistic regression, SVM, Random forrest, neural network) in R on a dataset of 224 GB while my RAM is only 16 GB.
I suppose a solution could be to rent a virtual PC in the cloud with 256 GB RAM. For example an EC2 at AWS based on an AMI from this post by Louis Aslett:
http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/

Alternatively I understood there are several parallel processing methods and packages. For example Sparklyr, Future and ff. Is parallel processing a solution to my problem of limited RAM? Or is parallel processing targetted at running code faster?

If I assume parallel processing is a solution, I assume I need to modify the processes within the machine learning packages. For example, logistic regression is done with this line of code:

> model <- glm ( Y ~., family=binomial ( link='logit' ), data=train )

Although as far as I know I don’t have influence over the calculations within the glm-method.

Comment: it might be worth taking a look at the [high-performance task view](https://cran.r-project.org/view=HighPerformanceComputing), which has a section on "large memory and out-of-memory data"

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you can't fit all the data in memory at once, and the standard `glm()` function needs that.  Luckily, linear and generalized linear models can be computed using the data in batches.  The issue is how to combine the computations between the batches.

Parallel algorithms need to break up datasets to send to workers, but if you only have one worker, you'd need to process them serially, so it's only the "breaking up" part that you need.  The `biglm` package in R can do that for your class of models.

Comment: @ user2554330 Thank you for your explanation. I also would like to do an SVM (package e1071), neural network (Keras) and Random Forest (randomForest). It seems biglm does not support these. Do you know the best setup to do these techniques with limited RAM?

Comment: No, I don't.  I'd probably try splitting the data at random into manageable pieces, then averaging the estimates that each piece produces.  I don't know of R packages to support this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [h2o](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/welcome.html). It has a lot of support for fitting logistic regression, <s>SVM</s>, Random Forrest, and neural network, among others.

Here's [how to install h2o in R](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/downloading.html#install-in-r)

I also didn't find `bigmemory` packages are limited in functionality available.

Comment: @ Suren. Thank you. Are you sure it contains SVM? If I look at the manual I don’t see SVM: https://www.h2o.ai/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/RBooklet.pdf

Comment: Looks like I was wrong about SVM. I saw [this](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/svm.html) and thought they have implemented SVM as well.

Comment: @ Suren. Thank you. You are right. It seems the manual I read was old. Although it seems to me H2O is a completely different application / environment than R if I understand correctly?

Comment: @Marcel h2o provides a framework for machine learning which **can be used in R** (among others).  I am not usre SVM is available to R though.